# django - PIL handling jpg and png files

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I have a function that handles uploaded jpg file but crashes when user upload png. How can I tweak (if possible) my function to also handle png files appropriately?

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from sys import getsizeof

image = self.cleaned_data.get("image")
if not image:
    image = ''
    return image
size = (145,145)

im = Image.open(image)
output = BytesIO()
im.thumbnail(size)
im.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=100)
output.seek(0)

image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output,'ImageField', "%s.jpg" %image.name.split('.')[0], 'image/jpeg', getsizeof(output), None)

return image
```

Comment: You save all images for only `jpg` format?

Comment: Can you tell me the `type` of `image` variable after this statement, `image = self.cleaned_data.get("image")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. Probably isn't the best method though.

```
    from PIL import Image
    from io import BytesIO
    from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
    from sys import getsizeof

    image = self.cleaned_data.get("image")
    if not image:
        image = ''
        return image

    size = (145,145)

    im = Image.open(image)
    output = BytesIO()
    im.thumbnail(size)
    try:
        im.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=100)
        output.seek(0)
        image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output,'ImageField', "%s.jpg" %image.name.split('.')[0], 'image/jpeg', getsizeof(output), None)
    except:
        im.save(output, format='PNG', quality=100)
        output.seek(0)
        image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output,'ImageField', "%s.png" %image.name.split('.')[0], 'image/png', getsizeof(output), None)

    return image
```